# asp.net mvc view of a controller inside of a view of an other controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

so i have a "Parents" controller with list and edit view for it (to view add/edit/delete parents)

and a "Children" controller same thing (view list add/edit/delete children)

and now i need to refactor; to put the children view inside the parent view, so that when you edit a parent you can see the list of his children and edit/delte/add some children

what's the best way to do that in asp.net mvc, 
is there any patterns for that or something

---

i tried to use RenderAction()
and it works fine it shows the list of users, but the problem is that 
you click the edit button for a users -> edit some data -> click save and you return not to the parent edit view with the list of users but just to the list of users view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a Partial View that is strongly typed to your Children's Class.

Then include that on your Parent's page using HTML.RenderPartial().

This can be updated using AJAX, if needed.

Comment: Agree 100%. You can have a partial view for your "Children Summary" which displays your list of children, which can be re-used wherever you need to show a list of children Maybe there is some mileage in having a "Person Summary", which can be used to list "People" not just "Children".

Comment: i tried to use RenderAction()
and it works fine it shows the list of users, but the problem is that 
you click the edit button for a users -> edit some data -> click save and you return not to the parent edit view with the list of users but just to the list of users view

Comment: In the Edit method of your controller, instead of returning the User View do a RedirectToAction("Parent", "Parents", new { id = parentID})

Comment: yes, probably that's how i should have done it, but i did it already